# Calculate power of a negative number

Tags: c#, linq

I relatively new to C# and since Math.Pow(x,y) returns NaN for a negative number(read: not negative power), I want to know how to calculate result more efficiently. What I am doing write now is a basic for loop, but I want to know if it can be implemented in *shorter* way (using Linq maybe)?

```
for(int i=0;i<power;i++)
       {
           result = result * num;
       }
```

Comment: You're saying that it returns `NaN` for something like `Math.pow(-2, 5)`?

Comment: Use Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x, y)) and then apply the correct sign. Math.Pow rejects negative x because "applying the correct sign" is impossible if y is not an integer.

Comment: The loop you posted will return 1 (assuming result is initialized at 1) with a negative number, which is not as correct as NaN.  If you are just interested in writing a more efficient power algorithm, you can use a divide and conquer method, see [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/) link (it's a `C` program, but translating to `C#` should be simple).

Comment: I was going to give Raymond's comment as the answer, but he beat me to it. Once correction, it should be Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x), y). Then if y is odd you negate the result other wise the result is positive. And y must be an integer value.

Comment: It will return 1 if power is negative which not the case. Anyhow the code is pretty good, I guess I can translate it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `Math.Pow(x,y)` returns `NaN` for a negative number.

That's because arbitrary exponentiation is not defined for a negative base:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

> when the base b is a positive real number, b to the n can be defined for all real and even complex exponents n via the exponential function

Now, exponentiation of negative numbers to get a real result is defined if the power is an integer, as in your case, but `Pow` will not calculate it for you.  What you should do is:

- Suppose you want to know `Pow(-2, 5)`
- Give `Pow` the problem `Pow(2, 5)` instead.
- Look at the exponent; if it is an even number then you've got the right answer. If it is an odd number, then make the answer negative.

So in this case, `Pow(2, 5)` returns 32. The exponent 5 is odd, so make it -32, and you're done.

Comment: I don't understand. `Pow(-2, 5)` does return `-32` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/ks8ObK

Comment: @Vedanshu One thing that *might* cause that is if your exponent isn't an integer, but is so close to an integer that you don't notice that it's not. `double a = -2, b = 4.999999999999999; Console.WriteLine("{0}^{1} = {2}", a, b, Math.Pow(a, b));` prints "-2^5 = NaN".

Answer (score 1):

in Pow(double base, double power), when **base < 0**  and **power** is *fractional* ( ex:  power=0.5) , then **NaN** will be generated, because it is calculable in complex domain not in real domain.
so may be you need to check the **base** and **power** of **pow** function before using them. in this case you should return your desired value as undefined value (instead of NaN).

the bellow function performs this operation, and returns 0 instead of NaN:

```
// pow with desired Nan
public double Pow(double x,double y){
    double MyNaN = 0; // or any desired value for Nan
    double result = MyNaN; 

    if (Math.Floor (y) != y) { // if y is fractional number
        if (x < 0)  // if x is negative number
            return result;
    }

    result = Math.Pow (x, y);
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use System.Numerics.Complex that can calculate Imaginary.

See:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/ComplexNumbers.aspx

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/3370/Complex-Math-Library-for-Csharp-and-VB-NET